# Graph API call 'unsupported URL'

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

When testing the following URL string out in the Graph Explorer I get the expected return

```
me?fields=albums.limit(10){name,photos.limit(1){images}}
```

But when calling

```
FBRequestConnection.startWithGraphPath("me?fields=albums.limit(10){photos}", 
                                        parameters: nil, 
                                        HTTPMethod: "GET") 
                                        { (connection: FBRequestConnection!, 
                                        result: AnyObject!, 
                                        error: NSError!) -> Void in
    println(result)
}
```

It says that it's an unsupported URL. Do I need to access these properties via the 'parameters' option instead? I so, how do I go about that? I can't seem to get my head around it.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Chris

Comment: Did you tried to reproduce the same url, with the values you use in your case in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ ? If so, same result ?

Comment: For me the default query "me?fields=albums.limit(10){photos}" works, so OR issues with your access token OR iOs(-sdk). Should not be API related.

Comment: @IanS. could you specify what you mean by OR issues? What does OR stand for?

Comment: Yeah, I tried it in the explorer and they work fine!

Comment: OR as in "option A OR option B" ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem when I tried to get my feed and found no answers. 
What I discovered is the URL format in Graph Explorer and iOS SDK is different.

iOS SDK don't like curly brackets, so your request for example should look like:

```
"me/albums?fields=photos"
```

In my case, that syntax works great. Unfortunately I have no idea how to specify the limit there.

//Edit: 
To use modifiers like limit, you can do that this way:

```
"me/albums?fields=photos&limit=10"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing the albums fields like this:

"me?fields=albums.limit(10).fields(images)"